# Accessing public variables from a c++ program

Tags: c++, vb.net, late-binding

I have a program written in VB2012 and I'm trying to do the heavy number crunching in a c++ DLL. There are lots of variables that the c++ program needs access to. What I would like to do it pass a Class object into the DLL (lets call it Class_fred) and the variables through the class.

VB code

```
class class_fred
   public var_1 = 10
   public var_2 = 20

   heavyLifter (&class_fred)

end class
```

C++ code

```
void heavyLifter (object* cf) {
  int a, b;
  a = cf->var_1 + cf->var_2;
}
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is fairly common. You can add a reference to your C++ DLL and pass it your object or work the other way around by making your .NET DLL Com Visible.

Comment: COM can work, but may be a little tedious.

Comment: You could make a POD structure to pass to C++ with the necessary info, you just need to make sure you get the marshalling right.

Answer (score 3):

In your VB.NET project, you'll want to add a reference to your C++ DLL. This can be done from the Solution Explorer in your project. Then, in your code, you can access it by passing it to your Fred objects. This code is a general example on how it can be done, using `HeavyDotNetClass` as your `Fred` class and `HeavyLifting` as the name of the COM assembly:

```
Imports HeavyLifting

Public Class HeavyDotNetClass
    Implements HeavyLifting.IHeavyObject

    Private _lifter As HeavyLifting.HeavyLifter
    Private _var1 As Integer = 10
    Private _var2 As Integer = 20

    Public Sub New(lifter As HeavyLifting.HeavyLifter)
        _lifter = lifter
    End Sub

    Public Property Var1 As Integer Implements _IHeavyObject.Var1
        Get
            Return _var1
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _var1 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Var2 As Integer Implements _IHeavyObject.Var2
        Get
            Return _var2
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _var2 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub Lift()
        If _lifter IsNot Nothing Then
            _lifter.Process(Me)
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

In your C++ DLL (imported as `HeavyLifting` here) you should define an Interface (`HeavyLifting.IHeavyObject`) that Class `Fred` will implement. In this example, the `IHeavyObject` interface has two properties, `Var1` and `Var2`.

You would then create an instance of your C++ object and pass it to an instance of `HeavyDotNetClass`:

```
Dim heavyLifter As New HeavyLifting.HeavyLifter
Dim heavyObject As New HeavyDotNetClass(heavyLifter)

heavyObject.Lift()
```

In this example, the C++ object would have a method called `Process` with a parameter of type `IHeavyObject`.